# Как получить подстроку из указателя?

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

Есть указатель

```
char *s="n1=1&n2=2&name=test&sername=test2";
```

Нужно из строки `name` взять значение, к примеру, `test` и записать в другую переменную.
Нужно найти значение между `name = &` и  следующим `&`

Comment: Это русский сайт. Пишите на русском пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно использовать string. Заносишь значение в него, после этого либо find либо substr. Тут уже на свой выбор.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вы можете это сделать таким образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "n1=1&n2=2&name=test&sername=test2";
    const char *t = "name=";
    std::string value;

    if ( const char *p = std::strstr( s, t ) )
    {
        p += std::strlen( t );
        const char *q = std::strchr( p, '&' );
        q == nullptr ? value.assign( p ) : value.assign( p, q - p );
    }

    std::cout << "value = \"" << value << '\"' << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
value = "test"
```

Можно также использовать строку для поиска `"&name="`. В этом случае только одна такая подстрока будет найдена в исходной строке.

Comment: Если бы `sername=test2` шло бы впереди, нашлось бы оно вместо нужного.

Comment: @sercxjo Это правильное замечание. В таком надо искать либо &name, либо проверять предшествующий символ.